# How to use powerShell and regular expressions to parse a text file

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to powerShell and need to input a text file, parse it to extract the data we need and write the result to a .csv file. However, at this point I still am unable to parse the file and am totally confused about which PS commands to use and how to incorporate regular expressions. While I could write out all of the ways I've tried to get this to work I think it would be more beneficial to just ask for help and then ask questions on anything I don't fully understand. FYI: we're running Win10 and my only 2 scripting options are batch or PowerShell.

We have a JSON file that was formatted by notepad++ and looks like this:

```
"issue": [{
    "field": [{
                   "name": "someName",
                   "value": [],
                   "values": []
                }], 
    "field": [{
                   "name": "numberinproject",
                   "value": ["81"],
                   "values": ["81"]
                }], 
    "field": [{
                   "name": "summary",
                   "value": ["This is a summary for 81."],
                   "values": ["This is a summary for 81."]
                }], 
           "comment":[{
                   "text": "someText for 81 - 01",
                   "markdown":false,
                   "created":0123456789101,
                   "updated":null,
                   "Author":"first.last01",
                   "permitted group":null
                },{
                   "text": "someText for 81 - 02",
                   "markdown":false,
                   "created":0123456789102,
                   "updated":null,
                   "Author":"first.last02",
                   "permitted group":null
                },{
                   "text": "someText for 81 - 03",
                   "markdown":false,
                   "created":0123456789103,
                   "updated":null,
                   "Author":"first.last03",
                   "permitted group":null
                }],
    "field": [{
                   "name": "someNameTwo",
                   "value": [],
                   "values": []
                }], 
    "field": [{
                   "name": "numberinproject",
                   "value": ["83"],
                   "values": ["83"]
                }], 
    "field": [{
                   "name": "summary",
                   "value": ["This is a summary for 83."],
                   "values": ["This is a summary for 83."]
                }], 
    "comment":[]            
            
   }
]
```

What I am attempting to do is extract the numberinproject, summary and Comment text, created and Author.
Notice that there could be Zero to multiple comments per project number.   The comment.created field is a 13 digit epoch number that has to be converted into mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM

I had hoped to export this data into a .csv file but at this time would be happy just getting the data parsed out of the file.

Thanks for whatever feedback you can give.

===================================================

By request: Here are some of the things I tried and I apologise for this being such a mess. Since the "json" file was not in a format that convertfrom-json could use I assumed the file was actually text and that is where this starts.

What I've picked up has been from Searching on the web. If anyone can suggest a good article, please let me know and I will read it.

```
Set-Variable -Name "inputFile" -Value "inputFile.txt"
Set-Variable -Name "outputTXTFile" -Value "outputTXTFile.txt"
Set-Variable -Name "outputFile" -Value "outputFile.csv"

numberinProject = \"value\"\:\s\[\"\d+   
summary = \"value\"\:\s\[\".+\"\],
comment - text = \"text\"\:\s\".+\",
comment - created = \"created\"\:\d{13}
comment - author = \"Author\"\:\"\w+\.\w+

## This actually worked. Though it grabbed the whole line, my plan was to then parse it a for a substring.
$results = Get-Content -Path $inputFile | Select-String -Pattern '"values": ' -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch 

# ------------------------------------------------
# However, If I tried using regex, the parse failed
$results = Get-Content -Path $inputFile | Select-String -Pattern \"values\"\:\s\[\"\d+ -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch
# I also tried this 
#$A = Get-ChildItem $inputFile | Select-String -Pattern '(<ID>\"value\"\:\s\[\"\d' 

# $results | Export-CSV $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
$results | Out-File $outputTXTFile 

# ---------------------------------------------------------

#I tried to output the file as a single string for manipulation - it didn't work
Get-Content -Path $inputFile) -join "`r`n" | Out-File $outputTXTFile

# I tried to use "patterns" to find the data but that didn't work

$issueIDPattern = "(<ID>\"value\"\:\s\[\"\d+)"
$summaryPattern = "\"value\"\:\s\[\".+\"\],"
$commentTextPattern = "\"text\"\:\s\".+\","
$commentDatePattern = "\"created\"\:\d{13}"
$commentAuthorPattern = "\"Author\"\:\"\w+\.\w+ 

 Get-ChildItem $inputFile|
     Select-String -Pattern $issueIDPattern |
    Foreach-Object {
        $ID = $_.Matches[0].Groups['ID'].Value
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            issueNum = $ID
        }
    }

### Also tried a variation of this
    
Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt) -join "`r`n" -Split "(?m)^(?=\S)" |
    Where{$_} | 
    ForEach{
        Clear-Variable commentauthor,commentcreated,commenttext,summary,numberinProject
        $commentcreated = @()
        $numberinProject = ($_ -split "`r`n")[0].trim()
        Switch -regex ($_ -split "`r`n"){
            "^\s+summary:" {$summary = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
            "^\s+.:\\" {$commentcreated += $_.trim();continue}
            "^\s+commenttext" {$commenttext = [RegEx]::Matches($_,"(?<=commenttext installed from )(.+?)(?= \[)").value;continue}
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{'numberinProject' = $numberinProject;'summary' = $summary; 'commenttext' = $commenttext; 'commentcreated' = $commentcreated}
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet?.  This will convert your JSON file to PowerShell objects that you can manipulate using standard PowerShell techniques.

Comment: Regex is the entirely wrong tool here, +1 for `ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: I agree, more than once I tried ConvertFrom-Json and got the message the document was not in the correct format. I really don't know json. So I then tried working with the file as just a text file.

Comment: The json you show is invalid. Is that the real file or the result after manipulating in notepad++ ? Test on jsonlint.com or https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: Theo, where I work I'm unable to copy or send the file in question.  What I did was copy a subset of the structure and fields and give everything non-Identifiable names so I could test parsing at home.  However, to answer your question: the file was the result of the notepad++ conversion. It was saved as someFileName.json.  I've never seen the actual, unconverted/unmanipulated json file.      When I got the message about the format not being correct I thought it must be a text file - just with a json extension.  I could ask the customers for the original json file.

Comment: I know you've tried a lot of different things, but you really do need to show us some of the things you've tried (script and result), so that we can understand how you're trying to solve the problem and what kind of errors you've encountered - especially on the `ConvertFrom-JSON` attempts you've made. And I know you can't post live data, but SO lives on the principle of the Minimum Reproducible Example.

Comment: @waitingforguacamole  Here are a few of the things I tried.  I never got to attempt an import into a .csv file

Comment: Thanks for that update. Do you have any say about the format, or is this format just GIVEN to you and you have to deal with it exactly as it's typed. I ask because this JSON doesn't pass lint - if I surround the whole thing in `{ }` that fixes one problem, but your "field" entries either need to be unique property names (not the name property inside the field) or they need to live in a collection like "fields"?

Comment: I understand. The person I got the file from said the original json file that was sent, was just a straight line of text that was impossible to read - we had to pick out those fields I mentioned and then enter those into a .csv file for import into Jira.   She looked at it in notepad++ but needed a json plugin to format the text to make it readable.  The general format you see ut what we saw after putting the json file in np++ and doing a Save.  I just spoke with her and was told she re-downloaded that original JSON file - 1 single long line of text.  So I now have that to work with.

Comment: For ConvertFrom-Json it doesn't matter if all is one single line (compressed). Just humans need it formatted to make sense of it all. If you want it formatted without someone messing it up in np++, copy the whole thing in an online json formatting tool like [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.org/).

Comment: OK, thanks Theo. I'll give it a try tomorrow or Monday - whenever I'm able to make it to the office.